# What is the easiest way to write a Visual Studio pdb file from the contents of a map file?

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, native, roslyn, pdb-files

We are often in a situation while debugging in Visual Studio where we need to analyze a call stack that may contain many different layers of C#, python (eg. python27.dll, so actually C) and other native code (Delphi). There can be multiple layers of each technology calling each other. If we look at the call stack in the Visual Studio Debugger we don't see the names of the Delphi methods. If we look at the call stack in the Borland debugger we don't see the .net stack frames.

So we thought it should be possible to create a minimal PDB or DBG file from the .map file that the Delphi build chain produces. We are ready to write a tool that reads the map file line by line and writes the content via an API to a PDB or DBG file. However we wouldn't like to write the code that writes the exact file format 'byte by byte' but rather have a high level API, preferably by writing C# code. If there is still an easier way - even better.

Having that PDB or DBG file we would then see the method names of all layers (C#, Python and Delphi) and that would make us happy. For Python, we would of course only see the 'native' stack inside the python.dll - that is exactly what we want.

Is it possible to write a dbg file from a map file? (The map file seems to contain at least the segments and the addresses of all methods).

What we already tried:

- many different open Github repositories (map2dbg, tds2pdb, etc): they
  all did produce output that visual studio would not read and it
  doesn't look like its worth investing time (IMHO)
- looking at microsoft.diasymreader: looks exactly like the API we are looking
  for. So far it seems we would need to analyze the Roslyn code to find
  out how to use the DiaSym writer

What is the easiest way to do that? Is there any good example we could look at?

Comment: I don't think that there is a tool out there (not that we could recommend it here, recommendation Qs are not accepted). So you'll just need to write the tool yourself.

Comment: You could use https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-pdbutil.html with the yaml2pdb subcommand. Converting the map to yaml is still not obvious but should be way easier than directly to pdb. At least that's an approach I wanted to try for a while now ...